# Merge / rationalize Windows registration-free COM tags

Tags: support, burninate-request, synonym-request

There are  <s>3</s>  **six** tags which refer to essentially the same thing:

- [regfreecom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regfreecom) (99 questions)
- [side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/side-by-side) (211 questions)
- [winsxs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winsxs) (76 questions)

<sub>Edit: I discovered a few more which are just variations of the above:</sub>

- [reg-free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reg-free) (5 questions)
- [registration-free-com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/registration-free-com) (24 questions)
- [sxs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sxs) (44 questions)

The overall concept is valuable and needs a tag, but not so many.

It seems to be a relatively small community of people who have knowledge and follow these tags - *this situation only fragments that small community* and almost certainly hurts the site by making it harder/take longer to provide good answers.

I propose that we keep [regfreecom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regfreecom) because it is slightly broader in meaning than the other two. (Registration-free COM is an approach to application deployment, and Windows side-by-side technology is the way it is usually implemented). In practice one almost always means the other, but the broader term at least leaves room for alternatives even if they are rare.

Further, although tag [side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/side-by-side) is widely used, it is used to lots of questions inappropriately because its name is too vague and people unfamiliar with Windows development obviously don't realize that. It should probably be removed altogether. I've recently removed it from several questions where it was misused.

The latter group of three I added later are just spelling variations on the first list.

So I would retag all of these to [regfreecom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regfreecom), make [winsxs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winsxs) its synonym, and delete [side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/side-by-side).

---

Note - since posting this originally I've removed a lot of the bad usages of [side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/side-by-side). Doesn't change my proposal above, however, since it will just get badly used again over time.

Comment: "Retag all" and "some use it inappropriately" does not seem to match. If we retag, we should do it right and try to understand whether the tag can just be removed or needs to be changed.

Comment: Would [tag:regfreecom] be more immediately understandable as [tag:regfree-com], [tag:reg-free-com] or [tag:registration-free-com]? Frankly, when I see [tag:regfreecom] it takes a noticeable fraction of a second to parse it (longer the first time).

Comment: @Mayken I think the hyphenation is helpful. reg-free-com is probably a little easier to read / type.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I agree, of course cases where the existing tags are misused should be corrected (and can be done first).

Comment: These are distinct concepts with no overlap, albeit that this isn't always obvious to the questioner.  In particular, [winsxs] has nothing to do with [regfreecom] so be sure to not blindly retag them.  That they have the same set of experts in common is somewhat accidental.  You have to understand the Windows manifest voodoo to post answers, once you do you can pretty much cover all of them.

Comment: @HansPassant I certainly defer to your judgement on which are distinct concepts! :)  I was not aware you can achieve reg-free COM without a SXS manifest, how is that done?